# Titanium TableView row column

Tags: uitableview, titanium

I have the following thing to do:

- Create a TableView with 2 columns
- When I click on the first column, the row should be removed
- When I click on the second column, the associated product should be displayed

I put an eventListener on the TableView which works fine. Unfortunately I have no idea how to separate the 1st column event from the 2nd column event. Any ideas?

Here is the source code:

```
var viewResults = Titanium.UI.createView({
  ...
});
...
for (rowId in rows) {
  var tableRow = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow();
  var rowDelete = Titanium.UI.createView({
    ...
  });
  tableRow.add(rowDelete);
  var rowProduct = Titanium.UI.createView({
    ...
  });
  tableRow.add(rowProduct);
  tblData.push(tableRow);
}
tblResults.setData(tblData);
... 
tblResults.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   if (firstColumn) {
     ...
   }else{
     ...
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom property to views which you are creating:

```
var rowDelete = Titanium.UI.createView({
    action: 'delete',
    ...
});
var rowProduct = Titanium.UI.createView({
    action: 'product',
    ...
});
```

and then in eventListener check event.source property:

```
tblResults.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (e.source.action === 'product') {
        ...
    } else if (e.source.action === 'delete') {
        ...
    }
});
```